# Using ddr2 and ddr3 together

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a Gigabyte board called  GA-EP45C-DS3. It has four DDR2 slots, and 2 DDR3 slots.

I would like to use them in parallel, and achieve the result of 12gb RAM.

Will it work?

see:
http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Products/Motherboard/Products_Overview.aspx?ProductID=2870

Answer (score 5):

"Mixed mode, populating DDR2 and DDR3 memory modules simultaneously is not supported." - Page 16 of the [User Manual](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/motherboard_manual_ga-ep45c-ds3(r)_e.pdf) which is linked from your link.

Comment: please post comments about where a question belongs as comments.  don't include them in your answer.  thanks!

Answer (score -2):

It is one way to use DDR3 in DDR2 mode. Why to downgrade DDR3? It does not make sense. DDR3 will have refresh rate that of DDR2. This could also cause memory corruption, or system instability.